# This review audit should really be marked as spam?

Tags: support, review-audits

There is this review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4736111

which is also marked as possible spam by the system:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

but the content didn't look at all like spam, it was just some short answer with related code.

The problem is that now when I access the link there is nothing at all displayed at all (just the spam warning) ..not the same what I have seen during the review, so unfortunately I cannot include exact test here.

Is that normal? Can someone explain why it was spam? Did I maybe see an edited version of the answer where the spammy part was already removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was the mod that deleted that post.

It is an late copy of the accepted answer so should have been flagged. However, the spam flag wasn't appropriate. I have no idea why I didn't clear (or even decline) the spam flag before deleting the post - unless it was one I came across via the review queues.

I have gone back and cleared the spam flag so it shouldn't cause any more trouble.

Comment: I understand, but in the review screen I don't see the other answers.. just the question and the answer to be reviewed. So it is impossible to notice the duplicate without navigating to the related question.. A really tricky review audit!!

Comment: @donfuxx - Well if you're unsure you're supposed to "skip" or go and look at the post in context - there's a link for that - so you can make a better decision. You don't **have** to act on every review.

Comment: I know that and in fact I skip quite regularly. The thing is now that I know that default review screen is not sufficient to consciously review the item (impossible to detect duplicated answers) I might just skip even more often than now..

Answer (score 5):

So the post *should* have been deleted, and it *is* of low quality, but it's not spam, it's just an exact duplicate of an answer posted a year and a half earlier.  Deleting the answer is fine, but the spam flags should have been declined by the mod before they deleted the post.

Not rejecting the spam flags is of course an easy mistake to make, especially if they noticed the post and decided to delete it by some reason other than seeing flags on that specific post.  If, for example, this user posted duplicate answers on a bunch of questions I could totally see a mod going and deleting them all, and they may not have noticed spam flags on some of these other posts to know to reject them first.