# Review audits can easily be bypassed

Tags: bug, review-audits

I have recently noticed that audits can easily be bypassed without any effort.

## About the issue

I know that the audits are [not designed to be fail-proof](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287670/review-audits-exploitable-able-to-see-real-review-stats-before-voting-on-the-re). But they are designed to prevent **mindless** clicks in the review queue. This method allows **exactly that**, which audits are designed to prevent.

A method that allows exactly what the system is designed to prevent is a bug, there is no other way to put it.

So either the system is useless and should be removed, or it has to be fixed.

## Repro steps

- Open a review queue
- Review items until you find what looks like an audit (they are often easy to spot if you pay any kind of attention)
- At this point, do not take any action on the item, but instead click "back" in your browser, then "forward"
- Now the audit is not reviewable anymore, and has to be skipped

Basically, I can click "Looks OK", go back, forward, click, back, forward, click... until I get a "This item is not reviewable". Then I click "Skip", and continue my mindless task.

With this method, I can review a complete queue in a few seconds without failing a single audit.

With my back/forward mouse buttons, I don't even have to move my hand, which reinforces the "mindless" part.

## About duplicates

For now, all the notifications of "the audits can be bypassed" topics require a minimum effort on the part of the reviewer, and most of the time require more effort than actually reading the audit in the first place, which are often easy answers.

What I found is that you can review a **whole queue** without reading anything, **without moving your mouse**, and **without failing a single audit**.

This is exactly what the audits are designed to prevent.

If this is not a bug, I don't know what is.

Comment: @rene : I'm really not sure about that one. I know the audits are not designed to not be exploitable at all, but **they are designed to prevent mindless reviews**. This method **allows mindless reviews**. That's a bug, for me.

Comment: Hm, it's not like there are no other systems in place to penalize robo-reviewers.

Comment: @Cerbrus : like what ?

Comment: [Like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system)

Comment: Yes, but this is all based on failed audits. My method allows to never fail one, ever.

Comment: But...if that was an audit you would already have failed it... you only get the next item from the queue pushed to you if you action-ed one...if you took the wrong reason, going back would not help you.

Comment: What? My method allows you to NEVER have to take any audit. Ever. Well, except if it's the first question in the queue. When you go back then forward, you **cannot** take the audit, you **have** to skip it. I don't know what you don't understand.

Comment: I have updated my question. Maybe it's more clear this way ? I'm really confused : except that the topics are "audit" in my post and the "duplicate", they have **nothing** in common. It's like marking two SO posts as duplicate because they both use C# and talk about databases.

Comment: OK, with your repro steps it becomes clear how you pull this off and I repro-ed it. I'm not sure though if re-opening would give you another answer then *we know the system is not water-tight, it is not designed to trick smart users because whatever you throw at them they'll find a way*

Comment: Thanks ! For a moment here I thought I would never be understood :) I agree that it's not *designed* to be failproof, but with this method you don't have to be smart. That's the problem imho.

Comment: And, at the very least, it's not a duplicate of the specified topic linked ;)

Comment: I consider clicking back and forward on browser buttons an highly intellectual activity, I only discovered them today ....