# Zero answers but accepted is "yes"

Tags: bug, review-audits, triage

Below is a screenshot of an audit in Triage. If you look at the circled info in the right hand column, you'll see that the audit claims that the question has zero answers but has an accepted one.

[image: Screenshot of triage audit that says the question has zero answers but has accepted one. Contains obligatory red circle.]

When you pass this audit all the other info on the right hand side changes:

[image: Screenshot of triage audit after it's passed where the other info on the right has been updated to be correct. The question actually has 6 answers.]

Is this a bug? It seems like if Stack Overflow wants to obfuscate information for audits, including pretending that it has no answers, that they would also pretend it hasn't accepted an answer either.

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287670/review-audits-exploitable-able-to-see-real-review-stats-before-voting-on-the-re ?

Comment: @rene - It's similar but that one is about the fact that you can follow the link to the real post and see the correct information. This question is about a discrepancy while you're in the Triage view of the question.

Comment: The whole point of the audits are to make sure you're paying attention. I'd say noticing that discrepancy is enough to show that you *are* paying attention.

Comment: @Rob - Sure but, unlike the link being there, changing everything except whether there's an accepted answer seems like a mistake. If it's actually a deliberate hint that this is an audit, that's fine with me.  (BTW, Thanks for fixing the mistake in my question.)

Comment: Rejoice; you were actually paying attention during the audit.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations! This audit served it's purpose. You were paying attention to the question and not just clicking "Looks OK".

The purpose of an audit it is ensure you are paying attention. You noticed something weird and then passed the audit. An audit may be disguised to look more inline with what you expect in the queues - upvotes show as 0 score, other answers show as 0, an excellently written post being detected as spam. All of these are ways to ensure you are watching what you are doing and not just clicking the button.

Keep paying attention in the queues. You did exactly what was expected.

Comment: So it's wrong on purpose?