# One more interesting review bug

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, review-audits

I just saw one interesting moment when was reviewing late answers:
[image]

Usually if I see there are another answers I press at it to read and to compare with this new one.

If there is no any answer (this means this one is the first) **other answers** field is `0` but **answers** field is `1`

But here we can see zeros in both fields so it means this new answer **ALREADY DELETED**! So it's clearly audit.

Is it correct or just bug?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287852/578411

Comment: @rene awesome explanation of audits. Thank you!

Comment: One way to successfully pass an audit is to realize it's an audit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Audits only need to be difficult enough to catch Robo-reviewers. Sadly experience tells us that a pretty low bar is required for that.

On the whole fixing this won't change things one way or the other.

Comment: Ok, so it is a bug but noone cares) Yep?
By the way: if it just anti-robo defence why the audit penalty is so hard: one time I've been waiting for 1 month to continue reviewing...

Comment: You can only wait 1 month if you've previously failed and been banned for 2 days, then carried on regardless and been banned for 7 days and then carried on regardless at which point you get a 20 day ban. Perhaps it's time to think about being more careful with your reviewing.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe there is no 20 days penalty. 7 and the month is the next. I suppose I'm careful enough. There are some answers where I suppose it's enough to be an answer (I check link and find it helpful) but community voted it's too bad. And this is why I fail audit sometimes. 
It is not the answer to my comment, but I got your point of view.