# Make review audits frequency more unpredictable

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

While doing reviews, it is common to feel like:

*"I've been reviewing for quite a while, the audit should come very soon"*

And after passing the audit, there come this feeling:

*"I just passed the audit, the next several reviews should be safe"*

And this could lead to irresponsible reviews.

---

Would it be better if the frequency of audits is more randomized, and maybe sometimes give two audits in a row?

Comment: You already can get them in very quick succession, these 2 I got were 3 minutes apart: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33675898, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33675905/, with a difference of only _7_ in the review IDs. I can't recall if I've ever had 2 in a row, but they're already far more random than you seem to realise.

Comment: Yes that "7 difference" is what I'm talking about in the post, one can feel safe for couple of reviews after the audit because of knowing that the next audit won't come in a row, or maybe 2 or 3 after.

Comment: i mean, there's probably more useful things to work on than making the audit system better at trapping people who are trying to do good for the network

Comment: @KevinB This isn't for the people who try to do good for the network, this is for the people who do reviews carelessly.

Comment: Sure, that's the intent of the audit system, however it's horrible at picking audits.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's a set probability of an audit each time you get a review. Thus, audits can come at any time. It's no more likely for your 10th review to be an audit than your first. That it appears that way is, primarily, a fallacy that's matching a pattern to what you're seeing. It is true that longer sequences of non-audits are less probable, but that doesn't change the probability of your next review being an audit. In other words, having 10 non-audits in a row is less likely than having 9 non-audits in a row, but the probability of #10 being an audit is the same as for #9.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan of people are doing reviews carelessly, presumably they'd just fail the reviews. If they *paid attention for reviews* I don't see how your suggestion would help, since they would presumably just do the same thing as before. Also, if they really paid attention for reviews, it seems they aren't *that* careless.

Comment: @VLAZ Not necessarily. People can be very careful when they know audit is coming, as there are [tricks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287670/review-audits-exploitable-able-to-see-real-review-stats-before-voting-on-the-re) to know if a review is an audit. After passing the audit, they continue to review carelessly for the next couple of reviews because they're pursuing some badges

Comment: Why does it seem you are stressing over passing or failing an audit? It’s very difficult to fail an audit if you are choosing the correct review actions

Comment: @SecurityHound Who is the "you" here? This post was meant as an improvement to the site, not some kind of self-thing. You may not know there are people who are actually like that.

Comment: @SecurityHound _"It’s very difficult to fail an audit if you are choosing the correct review actions"_ Seems like you failed to get the point of the post. There might be people who do reviews only for badges, which mean they don't pay attention to the posts they review by default. They know how to differentiate between good and bad posts, but most of the time they do reviews carelessly and rush to get badges

Comment: @DhafinRayhan you never ___know___ when an audit is coming. There's a set chance you'll get one, and whether or not you just had an audit doesn't affect that. You might as well get 3 in a row. You're luring yourself into a false sense of security.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's technical, but unfortunately based on my experience, I **can sense** when an audit is coming. It's **not something magical**, that's why I believe there's some discoverable pattern caused by how the audit algorithm is implemented. You said that it's possible to get 3 in a row, but you know it's very rare, right? The point of this post is to make it happen more often.

Comment: _*Rolls eyes*_  Yea, it's nothing magical. It's random. Your sense, if measured, would probably be wrong half the time any way.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not really! Robert Longson's answer proved that you were wrong about the 3 in a row thing. There is a "small no audit period" if you pass an audit, which is the main point of the second quote I wrote in the post. This is what makes up the "sense"

Comment: @DhafinRayhan - “There might be people who do reviews only for badges, which mean they don't pay attention to the posts they review by default.“ - if that is the case, then those users deserve lengthy review suspensions and potentially having badges removed. Choosing the wrong review action is harmful to the community. If you’re doing reviews for a badge…….stop…please.

Comment: @SecurityHound And again, what's with the "you" here? _"Choosing the wrong review action is harmful to the community"_ is exactly what this post is about. The proposed change would help the system stop these people.

Comment: The usual signal for me that a review is coming is it takes a LOT longer for the audit to load than the typical review.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan - You brought up users failing audits because they are not paying attention because they want to earn a badge. That seems very specific, and I said if that describes your motivation, it needs to stop because users with that motivation and failing audits and choosing the wrong review action is harmful to the community

Comment: @SecurityHound If it was my motivation, I wouldn't make this post in the first place. If I find a way that would allow bulglars to break into my neighborhood easily, does it mean I'm the bulglar? No. Am I going to tell the security about the vulnerability? Yes. This post is in harmony with your worries, that this action is _harmful to the community_ so there need to be a way to stop it

Answer (score 8):

There is a [small no audit period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170797/increasing-frequency-of-review-audits/170816#170816) if you pass an audit. That was introduced because people complained a lot about getting two (or more) audits in a row. It used to be longer but was decreased precisely to ensure people can't robo-review after an audit.

Active reviewers should get at least one audit per day apparently.

Beyond that, audits are random, although there is [Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226275/gradually-lowering-the-frequency-of-review-audits-for-users-proven-to-be-trustwo) that proposes decreasing their frequency if you pass lots of them.

Comment: The "no audit period" is exactly what I'm talking about! So in other words, my post is basically suggesting to occasionally turn off the no audit period for someone, allowing consecutive audits to happen sometimes. Knowing this, a (bad, careless) reviewer can no longer feel "safe" after passing an audit.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan as I said, the no audit period was created because people really really really hated consecutive audits and then complained a lot.

Comment: I see, but I guess because it was pretty common back then? So my suggestion is to add some probability for consecutive audits, at least not to make it 0%. With that, people know they can't rely on the fact that it will never happen (which make those careless reviewers, well, more careful)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan but you've not established that this is a problem. When have you seen people robo-reviewing but only immediately after an audit so they can get away with it? Edit your question with examples that prove your assertion.

Comment: If I find a way that would allow burglars to break into my neighborhood easily, should I wait until the case happens, or should I tell the security immediately?

Comment: If nobody in the world has ever had a burglary then worrying about burglaries is probably not worth it. I.e. we should respond to burglaries, not just to people worried about them without reason.

Comment: *one audit per day* ... an SE dev once mentioned that the probability is 2 audits every 50 review tasks.

Comment: @RobertLongson So the general consensus here is that the current audit system is good enough to catch people who are careless in reviewing? Or specifically, those badge-pursuers? Because such people (whose behavior I mentioned in the post) don't exist?

Comment: Not at all, the current audit system has may problems - there are legions of robo-reviewers but they don't wait for audits to mess up. This proposal is so narrow I can't see it helping.